# Proper Implementation of graph through adjacency list in c++ stl

Tags: c++, graph, stl, adjacency-list

I am trying to represent basic undirected graph through adjacency list in STL of C++. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
   {
       int no_vertices,no_edges;

       printf("Enter the no. of vertices and Edges : ");
       scanf("%d%d",&no_vertices,&no_edges);

       vector<pair<int,int> > graph[no_vertices];
       //Pair because we edge along with its weight!!

       printf("\nEnter the Edges along with their weight :");

       int s,d,weight;

       for(int i=0;i<no_edges;i++)
         {

           scanf("%d%d%d",&s,&d,&weight);
           graph[s].push_back(pair<int,int>(d,weight));

         }

       for(int i=0;i<no_vertices;i++)
          {
            vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator it = graph[i].begin();

            cout<<endl;

            while(it+1!= graph[i].end())
               {
                 printf("%d->",*it);
                 it++;
               }

            printf("%d",*it);

          }

     return 0;
 }
```

In the above code using I am trying to print each of the vertex along with each of its edge, the compiler prints something and then goes into some memory error or infinite loop.eg. input in above program V=4 E=4 and edges along with the weight are

```
0 1 4
1 2 5
1 5 2
3 1 3
```

Expected output-

```
0->1
1->2->5
2
3->1
```

but the output is

```
1
2->5
```

and then memory error or infinite loop. Please suggest improvements in my code??

–

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%d->",*it)`

This statement is invalid because `it` has type `vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator`. So `*it` has type `pair<int,int>` and you can't print it using `%d` which expects `int`.

Try something like this `printf("%d %d",it->first, it->second);`

Comment: I think Sameer is storing the destination and the weight, not source and destination in the pair

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you don't print the number of the origin vertice (it is not included in `graph[i]` but it is `i` itself). 
The second error is to print `*it` (a `std::pair`) instead of `it->first` (the actual `int`) as Ashot explained.
One possibility would be to write the last loop like this:

```
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<no_vertices; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", i);
        for (auto& e: graph[i]) {
            printf("->%d", e.first);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Using iterators explicitly:

```
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i<no_vertices; i++)
{
    printf("%d", i);
    vector<pair<int, int> >::iterator it = graph[i].begin();
    vector<pair<int, int> >::iterator it_end = graph[i].end();
    for (; it != it_end; it++) {
        printf("->%d", it->first);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Although the code above will solve your problem, I probably havn't explained properly why your current code produces an error:
As the source node is not a part of the vectors, `graph[2]` is an empty vector. So you initilize the iterator `ìt` with `graph[2].begin()` which is equal to `graph[2].end()`. 
As a consequence,

1. the check `while(it+1!= graph[2].end())`  will always return true (`it+1` will start one position BEHIND `graph[2].end()`).
2. `printf("%d->",*it);` dereferences an interator pointing to an invalid memory location.

Comment: @Sameer: the range based for loop (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) hides the iterator mechanics and makes the code (in my opinion) more readable, but if you want, I can give you a version with an explicit iterator.

Comment: Also if you could please refer me to some good tutorial on iterator. I cannot understand how exactly iterator is used and how it functions..

Comment: Also if I use the following loop instead of yours i.e for (int i = 0; i<no_vertices; i++)
          {
            printf("%d", i);
            
            if(!graph[i].empty())
              {
               vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator it = graph[i].begin();
               while(it != graph[i].end())
                    {
                     cout<<"->"<<graph[i].first//Error in this line says member function as first!
                     it++;
                    }
              }
            cout << endl;
          }

Comment: @Sameer: Done. Unfortunately I can't point you to a good source for iterators specifically. If you are a general c++ beginner, I can recommend "A Tour of C++ (C++ In-Depth)" by Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMB. Also why i cannot directly compare it with graph[i].end() and rather explicitly define iterator_end??

Comment: You can (and probably should).